# Wordpress index file css class overwrite child template style.css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I created a child template and I want to modify the navbar-default class in the style.css.

But when I use 'Inspect Element', I noticed that the index file is overwriting my CSS.
In my style.css I set the height 100px, but the index file also creating a height and this overwrite my setting.

How can I fix this?

[image: Here is an image from "Inpsect Element']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here index means inline `css` is written on the `HTML` output page itself using `<style>` tag, you can find it by view source and Find command in browser (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)

Check whether it is required or it can be omitted from server side `HTML` rendering, otherwise you have to use `CSS` hack of putting !important in your `CSS`.

Comment: I put !important in the CSS, and that actually helped to overwrite the inline CSS in the index file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow this https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes to import main theme css to child theme.